# I am having a good time every day!

Tags: meaning

> I am having a good time every day!

Is it grammatically correct? Or should it be only

> I have a good time every day!

Answer (score 1):

> I am having a good time every day!

I don't know the technical reason for it, but as a native English speaker, this just sounds wrong / awkward. I think it's because "having" is related to the present, and only one day is the present day at a time. Maybe the problem isn't grammatical but logical? I'm not certain. I don't have a lot of background in the formal, technical deep-end of English.

> I have a good time every day!

This sounds natural to me.

Comment: If we add "I am having a good time every day on my two-week holiday now"? Will it be OK?

Comment: @user1425 I'd say "I have been having a good time on my two-week holiday so far" ("so far" is optional, but it would feel strange to me to use "now" instead of "so far", since now is more about the present, and this is talking about the past and present).

Comment: But "I am reading this book every day this week/month." is OK.  It means that I have been doing it and going to continue doing it. Why can't one say the same using the verb "have"? We can get rid of NOW.

Comment: oh. I didn't know you intended to say "I am having a agood time today and will continue having a good day" (present and future). I assumed you meant "I have been having a good time so far" (past and present). I assumed so because I don't think I can be certain that I will be having a good time in the future. If that's what you want to say, though, I might phrase that as "I am having a good time and intend to keep that up for the rest of my two-week holiday".

Comment: Well, certain or not, it's a matter of faith